# Edge of rotated image when using tcolorbox and tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I'm using tikz to draw a square and tcolorbox skins to fill the square with an image. The problem is when I try to rotate the image.

```
\documentclass[margin=5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (0,0) node[rectangle,draw=none,minimum size=2cm, fill overzoom image=cat.png] {1};
    \path (2,0) node[rectangle,draw=none,minimum size=2cm, fill overzoom image*={angle=30}{cat.png}] {2};
    \draw[draw=none,rotate=30,fill overzoom image={cat.png}] (3,0) rectangle (4.5,-1.5) ;
    \draw (4,1) node{3};
    \draw[draw=none,rotate=30,fill shrink image={cat.png}] (4.5,0) rectangle (6.5,-2) ;
    \draw (5.5,2) node{4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives me:
[image]

The edges of [2] and [4] aren't smooth, whereas [3] crops the picture. What I want is to rotate 1.

Comment: I would not worry too much about the aliased edge, because it appears to be related to the rendering of your viewer. When zooming on the edge in a pdf viewer, the aliased pixelation will shrink too. That said, note that [2] will not work well for non-square images, because you are only rotating the image, but not the square that is clipping your image. Note furthermore that you can also rotate a node: e.g. you could add `rotate=30` to [1] and replace `overzoom` for `shrink` to replicate the result of [4] (but it won't solve the aliasing "issue").

Comment: @JJMDriessen I want to print and frame the finished document. Also, I'm cropping the images into squares before I use them.

Comment: In that case, did you make a test print and was the aliasing visible?

Comment: @JJMDriessen Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rotating a (bitmap/pixelized) picture, its edges may appear aliased, depending on the viewer, whereas vector-based edges (such as those from tikz) appear anti-aliased.

The picture's edges appear anti-aliased if they are cropped or bounded by vector-based edges. In your solutions (2) and (4), the image is not fully cropped or bounded, so (parts) of its edges appear aliased, as shown below (rectangle edges drawn with `draw=red`):

[image: original with red edges]

Having the node edge bound (coincide with) the image can be achieved using `path picture` and `includegraphics` options, which provide more controls than `fill shrink image` and `fill overzoom image`.

In particular, for the square image we can do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% \placesquareimage{imagefile}{size}{xcoordinate,ycoordinate}{rotation}
\newcommand{\placesquareimage}[4]{
    \node[rotate=#4,rectangle,minimum size=#2,draw=none,path picture={
        \node[transform shape] at (path picture bounding box.center){
            \includegraphics[height=#2]{#1}
        };
    }] at (#3) {};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% aliasing not visible
\placesquareimage{example-grid-100x100pt.jpg}{2cm}{0,0}{30};
\placesquareimage{example-grid-100x100pt.jpg}{1.5cm}{1.5,0.5}{-30};
% aliasing visible, by making the rectange slightly larger (only change: minimum size=2cm --> 2.1cm)
\node[rotate=30,rectangle,minimum size=2.1cm,draw=none,path picture={
    \node[transform shape] at (path picture bounding box.center){
        \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-grid-100x100pt.jpg}
    };
}] at (4,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

On the right side a rectangle that is intentionally larger to illustrate the difference.
[image: solution]

Comment: Thanks for that. I had guessed that a possible solution would be to bound the image but I couldn't work out how to do it.